# First course in probability with measure theory

Tags: probability, measure-theory

I am a math undergraduate. Our department has decided that the first course in probability is delivered using measure theoretic approach. No previous knowledge in measure theory is required for the course.

I would like to ask for your advice regarding books for first course in probability using measure theory. Any other advice will be great.

Thank you!

Comment: Are you familiar with Lebesgue measure on the reals / in Euclidean space? Learning the rudiments there is necessary for intuition about measures. I'm sure you can find some good online notes on this topic by googling.

Comment: @AreaMan I am not familiar with Lebesgue measure, nor we have had a real analysis(not calculus) course. I know that there are notes online, but not sure what is appropriate for beginners.

Comment: You should talk to your professor, who will know the course better and therefore should understand what will be required from students. Taking measure theory without any analysis background is not a great idea (since you will have to get used to epsilon Delta arguments very fast).